# Regular Expression to accept 1,2,3 or 2

Tags: regex, django

The following expression accepts `deal_status/2/`

```
(r'^deal_status/(?P<deal_id>\d+)/$', _deal_status_view),
```

But how do I accept any comma separated digit PLUS one digit without any comma?

`deal_status/2,3,5/`
or
`deal_status/2/`

Where do Django pros test the url regular expressions? Is there any online validator that could help me?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(r'^deal_status/(?P<deal_id>\d+(,\d+)*)/$', _deal_status_view),
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where do Django pros test the url regular expressions? Is there any online validator that could help me?

https://regex101.com/#python